# Best Way To Consume JSON from REST API in .NET

Tags: .net, rest

I'm working on a .net web app in c# and I need to consume a REST service from a third party (they are not using WCF). I'm coming from a background of using web service calls where there was a WSDL available and Visual Studio would build all of the underlying code and then I am ready to go.

Is there no tool or framework that can to some degree simulate this behavior? I understand that without a contract there is no way for a tool to know what to expect but I would think I could go through a wizard where I supply parameters to make a REST call and then help the wizard work out the details of the response. At the end of the process I would have a set of objects that model the REST API similar to how  the web service behave.

I know that REST and JSON have some great advantages to them but the lack of a standard out of the box contract to allow automated code generation seems like a real step backwards.

Am I missing something obvious or is that just the current state of affairs when consuming REST in .NET? Do I really need to write boiler plate code for each new API?

Comment: I'm not sure that this will help at all but you may want to take a look at the RESTful WCF WADL project: http://wadl.codeplex.com/

Comment: If you can connect to the REST service via HTTP on port 80, you should be able to connect to it using Visual studio and have the code generated for you.  What am I missing?

Comment: Phil do you have a sample of this? Are you adding the reference as a service reference? For example this url [link](http://api.justin.tv/api/clip/show/1278312.json?jsonp=) brings back a valid json object, how would you add this?

Comment: @phil - Are you sure that works with RESTful web services?

Answer (score 5):

You can look at using [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp) to access the REST API. I gave a sample, including an approach at using AutoMapper to go from data transfer object to domain model on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481366/mvc3-convert-json-from-rest-service-to-model/8481490#8481490).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at the [WCF REST Starter Kit All up page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/wcf/rest).

Download here: [WCF REST Starter Kit Preview 2](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24644)

Documentation here: [WCF Rest Starter Kit GUide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391967.aspx) Scroll down to 'Consuming RESTful Services with HttpClient'

You will end up using the ReadAsJasonDataContract e.g.

```
HttpResponseMessage resp = http.Get("friends_timeline.json");
resp.EnsureStatusIsSuccessful();
ProcessStatusesAsDataContract(resp.Content.ReadAsJsonDataContract<statusList>());
```

This looks to be a reasonable how-to [How-2 on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/ConsumeJson.aspx)

If you feel like being a bit more hands on and want to eek out more performance then doing your own web requests and using JSON.NET to handle the serialization is abnother good option. [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) (Disclosing that JSON.Net is written by a colleague)

Comment: I know the starter kit is required if you're running .NET 3.5, but what if I'm on .NET 4?

Comment: Yes. Sorry... should have ben clearer. The needed serialize/deserailize types are in .NET 4 natively.

Comment: REST Starter kit was obsolete years ago.  The latest work on this is here http://wcf.codeplex.com

Comment: @DarrelMiller - The WCF REST Starter Kit may not be under active development (I say *may* because I have yet to find anything stating it has been sunsetted), it is still pushed as *the* solution for .NET 3.5 development of RESTful web services in the WCF docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529. I understand what you are saying but when talking about old technologies like .NET 3.5 you are pretty much limited to only 'obsolete' technologies.

Comment: @M.Babcock If you read the license you will see that once MS releases the "official" version then you are required to upgrade.  The official version of RSK is in .net 4.  Therefore the license does not permit you to continue using RSK.

Comment: @DarrelMiller - Then they should stop promoting it.

Comment: @M.Babcock Yeah, I think it is more a case of people are too busy working on new stuff to worry about clearing out old and out-of-date documentation.